# how to display a username instead of user id in yii 2.0

Tags: php, yii2

I want to display User name instead of user id in admin panel :
[image]

i want to user name in filed f users

please give me solution its warmly appreciated in advance.

Comment: id and username in same table ? Please share some table details.

Comment: No the users are from different table . i am getting users id by

Comment: <?= $form->field($model, 'users_id')->dropDownList( ArrayHelper::map(user::find()->all(),'id','username'), ['prompt' => 'select']) ?>

Comment: have you assigned the relation in basemodel? Please check base model of this table. you will getUser or getUsers() method there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your index view file :

```
echo GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
   'columns' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                ['attribute' => 'user_id',
                    'header' => 'User Name',
                    'value' => function( $data ) {
                        return $data->user->username;  
// here user is your relation name in base model.
                    },
                ]
              ]
         ]);
```

Comment: it shows "Trying to get property of non-object" i do a relation in Jobs model like this:   public function relations() {
     return[
       'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'user', 'users_id'),
     ];
    
    } is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: i am working in yii 2.0.7 is there any other method ??

Comment: For my answer to work , your function in job base model should like this :

  public function getUser()
    {
    return $this->hasOne(Users::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
    }

If you don't have such method in your base model then you must generate the model again and overwrite the model.

Comment: now i am try same as jobs in blogs module but it  show "Trying to get property of non-object"  . i did everything same as jobs module but in blogs it show error. public function getUser() {
      
     return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id'=>'user_id']);
    }.this is the function i use for blogs ..and in grid view it looks like that  ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
    
          ['attribute' => 'user_id',
          'header' => 'User Name',
          'value' => function( $data ) {
          
          return $data->user->username;
           }],  plzz solve this.

Comment: You can not paste this function in base model. If your table blog has relation with user_id (users table) then by generating model that function automatically created in base model. Try to generate model for blog table and retry.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a relational table or model called users with id and name attribute.

You declare a relational data inside current model class or active record with --

```
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Users::className(), ['id' => 'users']);
}
```

Then in index view you modify the GridView to refer to relation User and attribute name by 'user.name' to replace the old users.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'id',
        //'users',
        'user.name',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Open your view file (path like **@app/views/user/index.php**)
Find string with:

```
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [ .... ]
```

array named 'columns' is what you need. You can swap id and username. Remove some columns, etc. Follow to [this doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html) for more details.